cant store file changes in cloud vs code
I work on my project from 2 pc, and have tried to use the build-in "cloud changes" feature, but then I use "store" it always says that: "Skipped storing working changes in the cloud as there are no edits to store."
what should I do to make it work?

Are you working within a Git repo that is hosted on either GitHub or Azure Repos?  That is a requirement to use the feature, as documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_74#_improvements-to-continue-working-on
